# How to map truthy values to separate objects in js/lodash in an object to array?

Tags: javascript

How to convert this using lodash/vanilla javascript

```
const obj = {
'red': {'1': true, '2': false, '3':true},
'green': {'1': false, '2': false, '3':true},
'blue': {'1': true, '2': true, '3':true},
}
```

to this:

```
const resultArray = 
[
{'red': '1'}, {'red': '3'},
{'green': '3'},
{'blue': '1'}, {'blue': '2'},
]
```

Here all the keys whose values are truthy are mapped to 'red', 'green' or 'blue' in array.

Comment: Is there anything you've tried that you're having trouble with?

Comment: Yeah. I've tried pickBy and some mapping. Not working out.

Comment: Please add your attempts to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you want to do is iterate all the object entries (keys => values) and for each of those, filter out the falsy values and map those entries your desired format.

You can then flatten the new array to get the final result you want.

```js
const obj = {
'red': {'1': true, '2': false, '3':true},
'green': {'1': false, '2': false, '3':true},
'blue': {'1': true, '2': true, '3':true},
}

const resultArray = Object.entries(obj).map(([ key, vals ]) => 
  Object.entries(vals)
    .filter(([ _, flag ]) => flag)
    .map(([ idx ]) => ({ [key]: idx }))
).flat()

console.info(resultArray)
```

Comment: If you downvote, please leave a comment as to why. I'd love to know how I could improve this answer

Answer (score 0):

```js
const obj = {
'red': {'1': true, '2': false, '3':true},
'green': {'1': false, '2': false, '3':true},
'blue': {'1': true, '2': true, '3':true},
};

const out = Object.keys(obj).flatMap(color => {
  return Object.entries(obj[color])
    .filter(([k, v]) => Boolean(v))
    .map(([k]) => ({[color]: k}));
});

console.log(out);
```